# How to get the closest previous different prop in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component with props:

```
function MyComponent({propA, propB, propC}) {
    ...
}
```

This component is rendered few times with different props values. I need to get the closest previous prop value which is not equal to current value. For example:

1. First render. propA is 1. previous value must be undefined
2. Second render. propA is 2. previous value must be 1
3. Third render. propA is 2. previous value must be 1 (not 2, because
   current value is 2)

There is a similar "usePrevious" hook:

```
export const usePrevious = <T>(value: T): T | undefined => {
  const ref = useRef<T>();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });

  return ref.current;
};
```

But it returns any previous value even if it has not changed. And it looks like I should modify this hook, but I don't know how

code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-snow-mkile?file=/src/index.js (props values are logged in console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const usePrevious = newValue => {
  const refPrev = useRef()
  const refCurr = useRef()

  if (newValue !== refCurr.current) {
    refPrev.current = refCurr.current;
    refCurr.current = newValue;
  }

  return refPrev.current;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-snow-mkile?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I see the issue. Updated, this appears to work in your sandbox.

Comment: Thank you very much Jacob! That’s what I’ve been looking for